# Is this rendering because of VM, or do i need to install something else? unity, 18.04

Tags: unity, virtualbox, 18.04, ubuntu-minimal, guest-os

In an attempt to avoid the gnome desktop completely, I installed Ubuntu from the minimal installer and installed Unity after with the command `sudo apt install ubuntu-unity-desktop`. This in VirtualBox.

For some reason nothing seems to move smoothly. There is a red marking where normally the box would just move (as in picture) and when switching workplace etc. It just jumps directly.

[image]

So does anyone know why this might be? Is there something I need to install or configure or is it because of the VM?

I have enabled the 3D acceleration on the VM. Here are the other settings of VM:

[image: VirtualBox settings]

Comment: this does not seem to be a problem with gnome

Comment: Did you install [Guest Additions](/q/22743/175814)?

Comment: Looks like Unity thinks there isn't sufficient 3D support for the usual effects and switched to its low-effect modus?

Comment: i installed guest additions, but i have no idea what to do with it further :S

Comment: I have to add that this is an experiment before installing 18.04 directly on drive.. i really wanna continue using unity, and i don't want anything from the new desktop to clutter it.

Comment: i installed guest additions.. no goodness happening.. still the same

Comment: i tried it for real on a computer... it was definitely the VM. works perfectly on laptop full install